# How can I make an image size responsive in splash screen?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a splash screen for my app by using flutter_native_splash package.I give  background color and an image to splash screen.However the image is not fit normally.What can I do?
[image: as you see here]

in pupspec dev dependencies I wrote like that :

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#B800FF"
  image: assets/images/parisa_splash.png
  android_12: 
    image: assets/images/parisa_splash.png
  android: true
```

I changed image size on Internet and made 512x512 but it did not help.
I tried almost all solutions in here but does not help...
I share the image that I attached to my app.Maybe the problem can be related to image...
[image: it is the 512x512 image]